# Best method to get distinct set of integers in C#

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

I want to add a set of two integer values into a list/array and get them sorted as a distinct group.

eg:- `{ {2,3},{2,3},{5,10},{5,2} }` should become `{ {2,3},{5,10},{5,2} }`
What is the best method to use array or lists?

Comment: Neither. If you want a set of data, use a set of data, not a list or array, neither of which is a representation of a set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really do just want to get all the distinct items, the easiest way is to use a list of `Tuple<int,int>` and then use `IEnumerable.Distinct()` to remove duplicates.

For example:

```
var data = new List<Tuple<int, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create(2, 3),
    Tuple.Create(2, 3),
    Tuple.Create(5, 10),
    Tuple.Create(5, 2)
};

var distinct = data.Distinct().ToList();

foreach (var tuple in distinct)
    Console.WriteLine(tuple);
```

This does not perform any ordering, but if you wanted to order the result you could use `OrderBy()` to select the element with which to order:

```
var distinct = data.Distinct().OrderBy(item => item.Item1).ToList();
```

This will order by the first element of each pair (because `Item1` is specified).

Comment: Thanks @Matthew Watson,

Comment: Why not use a HashSet instead of a list?

Comment: @aquinas You can't put duplicates into a hashset, so I couldn't demonstrate how to remove duplicates from a collection of entities that contains duplicates if that collection was a hashset.

Comment: "You can't put duplicates into a hashset" Well, exactly :) 

That's what I thought OP wanted. He mentioned wanting to add to a list, but it seems like he really should have been adding to a Set...

Comment: @aquinas It's hard to say from the OP. I assumed he had some sort of list already that he wanted to dedupe.